# Indentation error when using subprocess in Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, indentation

I have tried using a function defined using subprocess but I get an indentation error depending on where I put it on my code. A minimal example of my code is:

```
import subprocess

def runsafe(job,args):
    jobs=[job];
    for arg in args:
        jobs.append(arg)
    proc=subprocess.Popen(jobs,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    return proc.stdout.readlines()

if __name__=="__main__":
        runsafe("mkdir","Try")
    A=0
    B=7
```

This works and gives me the correct input (this code just creates three new folders called T, r, y where it's executed) but the indentation seems weird to me. A and B are just two constants that I will use later in the code.

For me the most natural would be to write:

```
import subprocess

def runsafe(job,args):
    jobs=[job];
    for arg in args:
        jobs.append(arg)
    proc=subprocess.Popen(jobs,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    return proc.stdout.readlines()

if __name__=="__main__":
    runsafe("mkdir","Try")
    A=0
    B=7
```

If I do this I just get:

> IndentationError: 'unexpected indent'

Why is it necessary to indent (again) the line where I call runsafe? Shouldn't it work if I use it like in the second example?

Comment: You are almost certainly mixing tabs and spaces. Don't do that.

Comment: If I run your code using only spaces (no tabs), the first snippet gives an indentation error, and the second runs fine (except for the fact that it creates three directories named `T`, `r`, and `y`, which probably isn't what you intended).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are very likely mixing tabs and spaces in your indentation. With Python 2 this often leads to weird behavior because mixing tabs and spaces actually works. But it doesn’t work in the way you would maybe expect: For Python 2, a tab is equivalent to *8 spaces*. So for evaluating the indentation level, every tab is replaced by 8 spaces.

So when you have an indentation like this (where a `.` is a space, and `---→` is a tab):

```
def test():
........pass
---→pass
```

then it might look weird but it is valid since everything is indented using 8 spaces.

So you should make sure that you are using *consistent* indentation (it doesn’t matter whether it’s spaces or tabs—as long as it’s consistent).

Btw.: In Python 3 this is no longer allowed and will throw a syntax error (actually a `TabError`) with an actually helpful message: `TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation`.

Comment: Thanks, I've changed the tab size of my editor and I've adjusted the indent and now everything is better. It is working now.

Comment: @Adolfo your editor (hopefully) should have a setting to convert tabs to spaces, and to indent only using spaces. It's best to not even have tab characters anywhere in your code at all. Just indent with 4 spaces and life will be better.

Comment: @MattDMo Please do me a favor and do not advertise any preference of spaces or tabs over the other in a comment to my answer. Using either is fine, as long as the use is consistent.

Comment: @poke The comment is perfectly valid, especially since it expresses the preference stated in [PEP 0008](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#tabs-or-spaces): *"Python 2 code indented with a mixture of tabs and spaces should be converted to using spaces exclusively"*

Comment: I'm simply recommending the use of [PEP-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#tabs-or-spaces) - "*Spaces are the preferred indentation method.*" I've seen way too many questions here with code mixing tabs and spaces, and have had issues of my own with others' code.

Comment: Yes, I absolutely know what PEP8 recommends, but I don’t care, and I’m simply asking you, not to do it in comments to my answers. The indentation problem is not caused by tabs, it’s caused by mixing indentation. People can use tabs properly for indentation without any issues, so let them if they want to.

Comment: @Adolfo: *"I've changed the tab size of my editor and I've adjusted the indent"* Suggests that you are still mixing tabs and spaces - to be clear *Don't do this* - it will bite you later on.

Comment: *Not* every tab is replaced by 8 spaces.

Answer (score 2):

Your code mixes tabs and spaces for indentation. While this was possible and allowed in Python 2, Python 2 assumes tab size of *8 spaces*. If you had an editor that has a setting to turn on visible whitespace, you'd see that one of the lines is indented with 8 spaces, and the other 2 with a single <kbd>TAB</kbd>:

```
if __name__=="__main__":
........runsafe("mkdir","Try")
--->A=0
--->B=7
```

That is, in your editor you had the tab display default to 4 spaces, while Python 2 expects 8 spaces to match a <kbd>TAB</kbd>.

As the tab size cannot be agreed on, yet in Python the indentation is significant, use of tabs for indentation is [*not* considered best practice](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#tabs-or-spaces) in either Python 2 or Python 3.

> Tabs should be used solely to remain consistent with code that is already indented with tabs:

**And mixing tabs and spaces in a way that makes indentation depend on the worth of a tab expressed in spaces is very wrong.**

---

In Python 2 the tab size is 8, so indentation of                             <kbd>TAB</kbd> counts the same as 8 spaces or single <kbd>TAB</kbd>. Unfortunately there are many code editors that do not realize this, and instead use a different tab size for Python 2 code. In Python 3 OTOH, a <kbd>TAB</kbd> is only matched by another <kbd>TAB</kbd>. A good Python 3 editor would then mark inconsistent use of tabs in indent as syntax errors.

Thus the only consistent way of using tabs is using *only* tabs for indentation. In Python 2 there is a switch for that; you can start your Python interpreter with option `-tt`, or put it on the `#!` line after the `python` command, which will cause Python 2 to throw an error if it ever meets a line which makes the indent depend on tab size.

However, if you're writing new code, please be advised that the Python community **almost uniformly** follows the PEP 8 coding conventions: indentations are 4 spaces, and *no tabs are used*. In my experience, it is only the ever so odd legacy project that does not obey this guideline. Nearly all open-source projects these days that have coding conventions also require 4-space indentation, as well as other aspects of [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008).